# Constexpr in visual studio 2015 update 3

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, constexpr

hmmm, i dont know if it is bug or what?
but it is compiled on old version

```
#pragma once
#include <string>
#include <array>
#include <cstdarg>

#define BEGIN_NAMESPACE( x ) namespace x {
#define END_NAMESPACE }

BEGIN_NAMESPACE(XorCompileTime)
constexpr auto time = __TIME__;
constexpr auto seed = static_cast<int>(time[7]) + static_cast<int>(time[6]) * 10 + static_cast<int>(time[4]) * 60 + static_cast<int>(time[3]) * 600 + static_cast<int>(time[1]) * 3600 + static_cast<int>(time[0]) * 36000;

template <int N>
struct RandomGenerator
{
private:
    static constexpr unsigned a = 16807; // 7^5
    static constexpr unsigned m = 2147483647; // 2^31 - 1

    static constexpr unsigned s = RandomGenerator<N - 1>::value;
    static constexpr unsigned lo = a * (s & 0xFFFF); // Multiply lower 16 bits by 16807
    static constexpr unsigned hi = a * (s >> 16); // Multiply higher 16 bits by 16807
    static constexpr unsigned lo2 = lo + ((hi & 0x7FFF) << 16); // Combine lower 15 bits of hi with lo's upper bits
    static constexpr unsigned hi2 = hi >> 15; // Discard lower 15 bits of hi
    static constexpr unsigned lo3 = lo2 + hi;

public:
    static constexpr unsigned max = m;
    static constexpr unsigned value = lo3 > m ? lo3 - m : lo3;
};

template <>
struct RandomGenerator<0>
{
    static constexpr unsigned value = seed;
};

template <int N, int M>
struct RandomInt
{
    static constexpr auto value = RandomGenerator<N + 1>::value % M;
};

template <int N>
struct RandomChar
{
    static const char value = static_cast<char>(1 + RandomInt<N, 0x7F - 1>::value);
};

template <size_t N, int K>
struct XorString
{
private:
    const char _key;
    std::array<char, N + 1> _encrypted;

    constexpr char enc(char c) const
    {
        return c ^ _key;
    }

    char dec(char c) const
    {
        return c ^ _key;
    }

public:
    template <size_t... Is>
    constexpr __forceinline XorString(const char* str, std::index_sequence<Is...>) : _key(RandomChar<K>::value), _encrypted{ enc(str[Is])... }
    {
    }

    __forceinline decltype(auto) decrypt(void)
    {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        {
            _encrypted[i] = dec(_encrypted[i]);
        }
        _encrypted[N] = '\0';
        return _encrypted.data();
    }
};

static auto w_printf = [](const char* fmt, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, fmt);
    vprintf_s(fmt, args);
    va_end(args);
};

static auto w_printf_s = [](const char* fmt, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, fmt);
    vprintf_s(fmt, args);
    va_end(args);
};

static auto w_sprintf = [](char* buf, const char* fmt, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, fmt);
    vsprintf(buf, fmt, args);
    va_end(args);
};

static auto w_sprintf_s = [](char* buf, size_t buf_size, const char* fmt, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, fmt);
    vsprintf_s(buf, buf_size, fmt, args);
    va_end(args);
};
static bool w_strcmp(const char* str1, const char* str2)
{
    return strcmp(str1, str2);
};

#ifdef NDEBUG
#define XorStr( s ) ( XorCompileTime::XorString< sizeof( s ) - 1, __COUNTER__ >( s, std::make_index_sequence< sizeof( s ) - 1>() ).decrypt() )
#else
#define XorStr( s ) ( s )
#endif

END_NAMESPACE
```

here are the errors:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C2127   'XorCompileTime::time': illegal initialization of 'constexpr' entity with a non-constant expression legit_projectv2 e:\project\legit projekt\xor.h  10  
Error   C2127   'XorCompileTime::seed': illegal initialization of 'constexpr' entity with a non-constant expression legit_projectv2 e:\project\legit projekt\xor.h  11  
Error   C2057   expected constant expression    legit_projectv2 e:\project\legit projekt\xor.h  35  
Error   C2061   syntax error : identifier 'index_sequence'  legit_projectv2 e:\project\legit projekt\xor.h  69  
Error   C2127   'XorCompileTime::time': illegal initialization of 'constexpr' entity with a non-constant expression legit_projectv2 e:\project\legit projekt\xor.h  10  
Error   C2127   'XorCompileTime::seed': illegal initialization of 'constexpr' entity with a non-constant expression legit_projectv2 e:\project\legit projekt\xor.h  11  
Error   C2057   expected constant expression    legit_projectv2 e:\project\legit projekt\xor.h  35  
Error   C2061   syntax error : identifier 'index_sequence'  legit_projectv2 e:\project\legit projekt\xor.h  69  
Error   C2127   'XorCompileTime::time': illegal initialization of 'constexpr' entity with a non-constant expression legit_projectv2 e:\project\legit projekt\xor.h  10  
Error   C2127   'XorCompileTime::seed': illegal initialization of 'constexpr' entity with a non-constant expression legit_projectv2 e:\project\legit projekt\xor.h  11  
Error   C2057   expected constant expression    legit_projectv2 e:\project\legit projekt\xor.h  35  
Error   C2061   syntax error : identifier 'index_sequence'  legit_projectv2 e:\project\legit projekt\xor.h  69  
Error   C2127   'XorCompileTime::time': illegal initialization of 'constexpr' entity with a non-constant expression legit_projectv2 e:\project\legit projekt\xor.h  10  
Error   C2127   'XorCompileTime::seed': illegal initialization of 'constexpr' entity with a non-constant expression legit_projectv2 e:\project\legit projekt\xor.h  11  
Error   C2057   expected constant expression    legit_projectv2 e:\project\legit projekt\xor.h  35  
Error   C2061   syntax error : identifier 'index_sequence'  legit_projectv2 e:\project\legit projekt\xor.h  69  
Error   C2127   'XorCompileTime::time': illegal initialization of 'constexpr' entity with a non-constant expression legit_projectv2 e:\project\legit projekt\xor.h  10  
Error   C2127   'XorCompileTime::seed': illegal initialization of 'constexpr' entity with a non-constant expression legit_projectv2 e:\project\legit projekt\xor.h  11  
Error   C2057   expected constant expression    legit_projectv2 e:\project\legit projekt\xor.h  35  
Error   C2061   syntax error : identifier 'index_sequence'  legit_projectv2 e:\project\legit projekt\xor.h  69  
Error   C2127   'XorCompileTime::time': illegal initialization of 'constexpr' entity with a non-constant expression legit_projectv2 e:\project\legit projekt\xor.h  10  
Error   C2127   'XorCompileTime::seed': illegal initialization of 'constexpr' entity with a non-constant expression legit_projectv2 e:\project\legit projekt\xor.h  11  
Error   C2057   expected constant expression    legit_projectv2 e:\project\legit projekt\xor.h  35  
Error   C2061   syntax error : identifier 'index_sequence'  legit_projectv2 e:\project\legit projekt\xor.h  69  
Error   C2127   'XorCompileTime::time': illegal initialization of 'constexpr' entity with a non-constant expression legit_projectv2 e:\project\legit projekt\xor.h  10  
Error   C2127   'XorCompileTime::seed': illegal initialization of 'constexpr' entity with a non-constant expression legit_projectv2 e:\project\legit projekt\xor.h  11  
Error   C2057   expected constant expression    legit_projectv2 e:\project\legit projekt\xor.h  35  
Error   C2061   syntax error : identifier 'index_sequence'  legit_projectv2 e:\project\legit projekt\xor.h  69  
Error   C2127   'XorCompileTime::time': illegal initialization of 'constexpr' entity with a non-constant expression legit_projectv2 e:\project\legit projekt\xor.h  10  
Error   C2127   'XorCompileTime::seed': illegal initialization of 'constexpr' entity with a non-constant expression legit_projectv2 e:\project\legit projekt\xor.h  11  
Error   C2057   expected constant expression    legit_projectv2 e:\project\legit projekt\xor.h  35  
Error   C2061   syntax error : identifier 'index_sequence'  legit_projectv2 e:\project\legit projekt\xor.h  69  
Error   C2127   'XorCompileTime::time': illegal initialization of 'constexpr' entity with a non-constant expression legit_projectv2 e:\project\legit projekt\xor.h  10  
Error   C2127   'XorCompileTime::seed': illegal initialization of 'constexpr' entity with a non-constant expression legit_projectv2 e:\project\legit projekt\xor.h  11  
Error   C2057   expected constant expression    legit_projectv2 e:\project\legit projekt\xor.h  35  
Error   C2061   syntax error : identifier 'index_sequence'  legit_projectv2 e:\project\legit projekt\xor.h  69  
Error   C2127   'XorCompileTime::time': illegal initialization of 'constexpr' entity with a non-constant expression legit_projectv2 e:\project\legit projekt\xor.h  10  
Error   C2127   'XorCompileTime::seed': illegal initialization of 'constexpr' entity with a non-constant expression legit_projectv2 e:\project\legit projekt\xor.h  11  
Error   C2057   expected constant expression    legit_projectv2 e:\project\legit projekt\xor.h  35  
Error   C2061   syntax error : identifier 'index_sequence'  legit_projectv2 e:\project\legit projekt\xor.h  69  
Error   C2127   'XorCompileTime::time': illegal initialization of 'constexpr' entity with a non-constant expression legit_projectv2 e:\project\legit projekt\xor.h  10  
Error   C2127   'XorCompileTime::seed': illegal initialization of 'constexpr' entity with a non-constant expression legit_projectv2 e:\project\legit projekt\xor.h  11  
Error   C2057   expected constant expression    legit_projectv2 e:\project\legit projekt\xor.h  35  
Error   C2061   syntax error : identifier 'index_sequence'  legit_projectv2 e:\project\legit projekt\xor.h  69  
Error   C2127   'XorCompileTime::time': illegal initialization of 'constexpr' entity with a non-constant expression legit_projectv2 e:\project\legit projekt\xor.h  10  
Error   C2127   'XorCompileTime::seed': illegal initialization of 'constexpr' entity with a non-constant expression legit_projectv2 e:\project\legit projekt\xor.h  11  
Error   C2057   expected constant expression    legit_projectv2 e:\project\legit projekt\xor.h  35  
Error   C2061   syntax error : identifier 'index_sequence'  legit_projectv2 e:\project\legit projekt\xor.h  69  
Error   C2127   'XorCompileTime::time': illegal initialization of 'constexpr' entity with a non-constant expression legit_projectv2 e:\project\legit projekt\xor.h  10  
Error   C2127   'XorCompileTime::seed': illegal initialization of 'constexpr' entity with a non-constant expression legit_projectv2 e:\project\legit projekt\xor.h  11  
Error   C2057   expected constant expression    legit_projectv2 e:\project\legit projekt\xor.h  35  
Error   C2061   syntax error : identifier 'index_sequence'  legit_projectv2 e:\project\legit projekt\xor.h  69  
Error   C2127   'XorCompileTime::time': illegal initialization of 'constexpr' entity with a non-constant expression legit_projectv2 e:\project\legit projekt\xor.h  10  
Error   C2127   'XorCompileTime::seed': illegal initialization of 'constexpr' entity with a non-constant expression legit_projectv2 e:\project\legit projekt\xor.h  11  
Error   C2057   expected constant expression    legit_projectv2 e:\project\legit projekt\xor.h  35  
Error   C2061   syntax error : identifier 'index_sequence'  legit_projectv2 e:\project\legit projekt\xor.h  69  
Error   C2127   'XorCompileTime::time': illegal initialization of 'constexpr' entity with a non-constant expression legit_projectv2 e:\project\legit projekt\xor.h  10  
Error   C2127   'XorCompileTime::seed': illegal initialization of 'constexpr' entity with a non-constant expression legit_projectv2 e:\project\legit projekt\xor.h  11  
Error   C2057   expected constant expression    legit_projectv2 e:\project\legit projekt\xor.h  35  
Error   C2061   syntax error : identifier 'index_sequence'  legit_projectv2 e:\project\legit projekt\xor.h  69  
Error   C2127   'XorCompileTime::time': illegal initialization of 'constexpr' entity with a non-constant expression legit_projectv2 e:\project\legit projekt\xor.h  10  
Error   C2127   'XorCompileTime::seed': illegal initialization of 'constexpr' entity with a non-constant expression legit_projectv2 e:\project\legit projekt\xor.h  11  
Error   C2057   expected constant expression    legit_projectv2 e:\project\legit projekt\xor.h  35  
Error   C2061   syntax error : identifier 'index_sequence'  legit_projectv2 e:\project\legit projekt\xor.h  69  
Error   C2127   'XorCompileTime::time': illegal initialization of 'constexpr' entity with a non-constant expression legit_projectv2 e:\project\legit projekt\xor.h  10  
Error   C2127   'XorCompileTime::seed': illegal initialization of 'constexpr' entity with a non-constant expression legit_projectv2 e:\project\legit projekt\xor.h  11  
Error   C2057   expected constant expression    legit_projectv2 e:\project\legit projekt\xor.h  35  
Error   C2061   syntax error : identifier 'index_sequence'  legit_projectv2 e:\project\legit projekt\xor.h  69  
Error   C2127   'XorCompileTime::time': illegal initialization of 'constexpr' entity with a non-constant expression legit_projectv2 e:\project\legit projekt\xor.h  10  
Error   C2127   'XorCompileTime::seed': illegal initialization of 'constexpr' entity with a non-constant expression legit_projectv2 e:\project\legit projekt\xor.h  11  
Error   C2057   expected constant expression    legit_projectv2 e:\project\legit projekt\xor.h  35  
Error   C2061   syntax error : identifier 'index_sequence'  legit_projectv2 e:\project\legit projekt\xor.h  69  
Error   C2127   'XorCompileTime::time': illegal initialization of 'constexpr' entity with a non-constant expression legit_projectv2 e:\project\legit projekt\xor.h  10  
Error   C2127   'XorCompileTime::seed': illegal initialization of 'constexpr' entity with a non-constant expression legit_projectv2 e:\project\legit projekt\xor.h  11  
Error   C2057   expected constant expression    legit_projectv2 e:\project\legit projekt\xor.h  35  
Error   C2061   syntax error : identifier 'index_sequence'  legit_projectv2 e:\project\legit projekt\xor.h  69  
Error   C2127   'XorCompileTime::time': illegal initialization of 'constexpr' entity with a non-constant expression legit_projectv2 e:\project\legit projekt\xor.h  10  
Error   C2127   'XorCompileTime::seed': illegal initialization of 'constexpr' entity with a non-constant expression legit_projectv2 e:\project\legit projekt\xor.h  11  
Error   C2057   expected constant expression    legit_projectv2 e:\project\legit projekt\xor.h  35  
Error   C2061   syntax error : identifier 'index_sequence'  legit_projectv2 e:\project\legit projekt\xor.h  69  
Error   C2127   'XorCompileTime::time': illegal initialization of 'constexpr' entity with a non-constant expression legit_projectv2 e:\project\legit projekt\xor.h  10  
Error   C2127   'XorCompileTime::seed': illegal initialization of 'constexpr' entity with a non-constant expression legit_projectv2 e:\project\legit projekt\xor.h  11  
Error   C2057   expected constant expression    legit_projectv2 e:\project\legit projekt\xor.h  35  
Error   C2061   syntax error : identifier 'index_sequence'  legit_projectv2 e:\project\legit projekt\xor.h  69  
Error   C2127   'XorCompileTime::time': illegal initialization of 'constexpr' entity with a non-constant expression legit_projectv2 e:\project\legit projekt\xor.h  10  
Error   C2127   'XorCompileTime::seed': illegal initialization of 'constexpr' entity with a non-constant expression legit_projectv2 e:\project\legit projekt\xor.h  11  
Error   C2057   expected constant expression    legit_projectv2 e:\project\legit projekt\xor.h  35  
Error   C2061   syntax error : identifier 'index_sequence'  legit_projectv2 e:\project\legit projekt\xor.h  69  
Error   C2127   'XorCompileTime::time': illegal initialization of 'constexpr' entity with a non-constant expression legit_projectv2 e:\project\legit projekt\xor.h  10  
Error   C2127   'XorCompileTime::seed': illegal initialization of 'constexpr' entity with a non-constant expression legit_projectv2 e:\project\legit projekt\xor.h  11  
Error   C2057   expected constant expression    legit_projectv2 e:\project\legit projekt\xor.h  35  
Error   C2061   syntax error : identifier 'index_sequence'  legit_projectv2 e:\project\legit projekt\xor.h  69
```

should i downgrade or revert my visual studio to old version?
i dont really know what to do, does c++ updates and revised the use of auto and constexpr? 
please give me a hint on what to do, i am stuck up to this file
or is there another way to declare the variables but same behavior ?

Comment: Pare it down. Post a [MCVE].

Comment: Compiles with VS2017, so perhaps you should upgrade instead of downgrade?